# What happen to the initial 3DS device after a system transfer?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I'm thinking of buying a 3DS XL soon and I'd like to do a system transfer to that new device. Is there anything I should know before proceeding?

Also what happens to the first device after the transfer? Does it retain its data or is it wiped?

I'd love to give that 3DS to my girlfriend so we could play together but unfortunately all my games are digital. Is there any ways of giving games to her? (She had games on my 3DS)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the state of the first device, it will be back in the state it first was with regards to  Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection IDs

> **If I transfer Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection IDs, will both systems have the same ID number?**
>
> A Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection ID can only be used by one DS at a time. By transferring a Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection ID, the system you transferred it from will no longer have an ID. To get a new ID for that system, you will need to connect to the Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection. The system will then automatically acquire a new ID. (Do not do this with a game that uses the original ID, as it will erase your current Friend Codes.)

More information can be found on the [nintendo website](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/wfc/en_na/ds/transferID.jsp)

No, you can't split a collection of digital games between two Nintendo DS systems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Another question: I have a big SD cart on 3DS 1 and I want to use it on 3DS 2 after the system transfer. How do I do this? Does it transfer the whole data or only the purchases so when I'll plug my old card in the 3DS 2 it will directly work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is swap the SD cards. This will give you more space to download games, but also transfers save-data if it was backed up to the SD card. If you transferred everything, your games should already be there. Hope this helped!